# How safe is it to fly on a 22 year old Thai Airways Boeing 777-200?

Tags: air-travel, safety, aircraft, boeing

I am travelling to Bangkok and just got to know that I will be flying on a  22 year old Thai Airways Boeing 777-200, how safe is it to fly on a plane this old?

[image]

Comment: Extremely safe! Far safer than driving your new BWM to the airport to catch that flight!

Comment: It's never crashed in 22 years ;)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105309/discussion-on-question-by-rajdeep-singh-how-safe-is-it-to-fly-on-a-22-year-old-t). If you want to add to the comments, please go to the chat. The comments here will be temporarily closed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the myth here is that an older aircraft isn't safer because of wear and tear. That's not really true due to maintenance requirements. If you want to, you could fly in a [Douglas DC-3 (1930s aircraft) today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_DC-3#Douglas_DC-3_today) if you had enough time and money to find the operator. Any aircraft can be operated if it is still maintained.

The reason aircraft get retired from commercial airlines is generally they become **expensive to maintain**, not because they stopped being airworthy. Airlines don't buy one airplane, they buy a fleet, which includes the maintenance portion. The larger picture there is you need

1. Trained pilots
2. Mechanics to repair them
3. Available parts

It's #3 that will eventually drive an aircraft out of general use. Delta, which flies the MD-80/88/90 series, is set to [retire the aircraft in 2022](https://thepointsguy.com/news/three-years-left-to-fly-a-mad-dog-on-delta/).

> Delta will remove the MD-90 two-years earlier than previous plans to “realize fleet simplification benefits,” said Jacobson during the airline’s second quarter earnings call on July 11. The airline will replace the aircraft with ones from its current orderbook, which includes 77 Airbus A220s(sic, likely A320) and 144 Airbus A321s and A321neos, he added.
>
> The early retirement of some MD-90s was understood to be to support the in-service fleet, with parts from the removed aircraft available to support operational aircraft.

In other words, Delta cannibalized some of its fleet for parts, and may be actively doing so with its rolling retirement. McDonnell-Douglass (who made the planes) is now owned by Boeing, and [production of the MD-90 ceased in 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_MD-90). These planes can still be flown after Delta retires them, but Delta will have a hard time (i.e. expensive) sourcing new parts, which makes less sense for an active carrier airline operating thousands of aircraft around the world. Other aircraft of similar size are in production and their parts are more plentiful.

The planes will be sold to secondary carriers. You might have seen one in the news recently, when the US government chartered a flight with [Kalitta Air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalitta_Air) (likely operating a 747-400) to [evacuate US citizens exposed to the coronavirus](https://www.cnn.com/asia/live-news/coronavirus-outbreak-02-16-20-intl-hnk/index.html). These companies operate smaller fleets and, since they get cheaper used aircraft, the increased cost of finding parts will be offset.

## TL;DR

The Boeing 777 is still in production. It is as safe as any aircraft in commercial airline use, regardless of age.

Comment: These guys are still flying old aircraft regularly in Northwest Territories Canada  https://www.buffaloairways.com/index.php?page=aircraft-fleet

Comment: DC-3s are retrofitted with more efficient turboprop engines and used in remote areas and for military/commercial- see the Basler BT-67, they've made scores of them.

Comment: Lack of parts is a large factor of what ended the Concorde program.

Answer (score 92):

The age of the aircraft has never been the root cause of an aviation catastrophe. It's the maintenance, the crew and the safety policies/procedures of the airline.

A new aircraft that is not maintained well or being operated by a bad crew for an airline that does not have good safety practices is far more dangerous than a 30-year-old well-maintained aircraft that is being operated by an experienced crew in an airline that knows how to enforce good safety practices.

Comment: Well, my brothers own plane is from 1949 (71 years old today), the only issue is that you have to open the windows sometimes during flight to let fresh air in 

Comment: You could mention the Boeing 737 Max as an example that newer airplanes aren't necessarily that much safer.

Comment: Is it ***really statistically true*** that aircraft age is not correlated to, well, deaths?

Comment: @Fattie out of [7 accidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Accidents_and_incidents_involving_the_Boeing_777) involving a B777-200 (excluding the shootdown of the Malaysian), the ages of the aircraft where 7,7,12,14,16,21 years. This proves my point considering that many of the B777-200s were produced in the late 1990s or beginning of the 2000s.

Comment: Isn't [Southwest 1380](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southwest_Airlines_Flight_1380) a counterexample? Age does cause metal fatigue. *"NTSB determines that the probable cause of this accident was a low-cycle fatigue crack in the dovetail of fan blade No. 13..."*

Comment: @smci that's a maintenance problem.

Comment: @smci Engines are on a different replace schedule, anyway. A 22yo plane may have brand new engines, and a new plane may inherit a set of engines nearing their EOL (which is shorter than that of planes)

Comment: @NeanDerThal: that's way too vague: was the root-cause a) Boeing did not recommend adequate maintenance b) the FAA did not or c) that Southwest did not do the minimum maintenance required by them? or d) above and beyond the minimum required. I remember reading around the time that d) Southwest was accused of skimping on maintenance to cut costs. But the NTSB report makes it look like a)/b).

Comment: @alamar: Right. That implication wasn't clear to me from your post. You might like to spell it out explicitly.

Comment: @Fattie the answer does not make that claim.

Comment: @Fattie remember you have to factor for design improvements. A sixty year old design like a 707  doesn't necessarily have feedback slat warnings, hydraulic fuses, door latch interlocks, flushed FOHE tubes, hardened cockpit doors,  and other things that were discovered to be important only from subsequent accidents, and added to subsequent generations.

Comment: @NeanDerThal only if you take into account the distribution of the ages of the planes. Do you have that figure?

Comment: @njzk2 As I said in the comment, mostly were delivered by the end of 1990s or beginning of 2000s, check this page: http://active.boeing.com/commercial/orders/displaystandardreport.cfm?cboCurrentModel=777&optReportType=AllModels&cboAllModel=777&ViewReportF=View+Report

Comment: interesting point @Harper-ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 32):

If you look at the average age of aircraft, 22 years isn't actually that bad.

https://www.bts.gov/content/average-age-aircraft

I'd be more interested in checking out the accident rating of the individual carrier. Do they service their aircraft properly. Do they maintain them in the top standards... If they do, nothing to worry about.

Following On, 2017:

https://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/destinations/asia/thailand/articles/thailand-air-safety-rating-upgraded/

They have been under serious scrutiny so things will have been done right!

Comment: "They have been under serious scrutiny so things will have been done right!" That's not necessarily true, but in this case it looks like they've made significant improvements.

Comment: They have a safety rating of 5/7 on https://www.airlineratings.com/safety-rating-tool/

Comment: @padd13ear I'm not sure I trust the rating particularly. Are norwegian and easyJet really that insecure just because they don't have a presumably pretty expensive certification?

Comment: I can at least say that I have never heard of any safety incidents ever related to Norwegian. Source: I am norwegian, and read a lot of norwegian news, where it absolutely would be written about. They write a lot about delays, cancellations, stock value changes etc when they happen to the airline.

Comment: @padd13ear a perfect score!

Comment: @Voo I didn't really mean to imply that the overall rating should be trusted blindly. More to draw the OP's attention to the existence of the website, where the various factors that go into the rating are at least clearly presented.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a thought, to complement what other answers explain about maintenance and safety.

At the moment of writing this, there are 166 Boeing 777-200 in flight:

[image]

This happens 24 hours a day, 365 days a year, and you never hear about it. That's how safe flying is.

If you extend to the whole Boeing 777-family, the number of aircraft in flight at this very moment increases to 680, and the picture looks like this:

[image]

The pictures are from [Flight Radar 24](https://flightradar24.com).

Comment: That's a relief!

Answer (score -6):

Yes good maintenance practices and regular overhauls by the aircrafts operator reduce the chances of an accident but in my opinion the chances of a component failure do to metal fatigue increases with the age of the aircraft, This is because every time an aircraft is pressurised, lands and takes off significant forces act on all the structural components. Unless the aircraft is completely dismantled, NDT'd (non distructive testing) some small stress fractures can go undescovered.
Also newer aircraft have better, stronger and more resilient materials of manufacture.
Therefore you are more likely to have an incident on an older aircraft compared to a newer aircraft.

Comment: Can you please edit in proof of your claim?

Comment: What you describe in your "Unless the aircraft is completely dismantled..." sentence is known as an [aviation D-check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_maintenance_checks#D_check), and is done about every ten years.  Metal fatigue has been a major concern of aircraft designers since the time of the De Havilland Comet, and every part on an aircraft has a rating of how many fatigue cycles it can undergo before it needs replacement.